# How to add a field to a document which contains the result of the comparison of two other fields

Tags: mongodb

I would like to speed up an query on my mongoDB which uses $where to compare two fields in the document, which seems to be really slow.

My query look like this:

```
db.mycollection.find({ $where : "this.lastCheckDate < this.modificationDate})
```

What I would like to do is add a field to my document, i.e. `isCheckDateLowerThenModDate`, on which I could execute a probably much faster query:

```
db.mycollection.find({"isCheckDateLowerThenModDate":true})
```

I quite new to mongoDB an have no idea how to do this. I would appreciate if someone could give me some hints or examples on

1. How to initialize such a field on an existing collection
2. How to maintain this field. Which means how to update this field when `lastCheckDate` or `modificationDate` changes.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking in a right way!

> 1.How to initialize such a field on an existing collection.

Most simple way is to load each document (from your language), calculate this field, update and save.

Or you could perform an update via mongo shell:

```
db.mycollection.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
   if(doc.lastCheckDate < doc.modificationDate)
   {
     doc.isCheckDateLowerThenModDate = true;
   }
   else
   {
     doc.isCheckDateLowerThenModDate = false;
   }
   db.mycollection.save(doc); 
});
```

> 2.How to maintain this field. Which means how to update this field when
>   lastCheckDate or modificationDate changes.

You have to do it yourself from your client code. Make some wrapper for update, save operations and recalculate this value each time there. To be absolutely sure that this update works -- write unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

The [`$where` clause](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D) is slow because it is evaluating each document using the JavaScript interpreter.

There are a few alternatives:

1) Assuming your use case is "look for records that need updating", take advantage of a [sparse index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-sparse%3Atrue):

- add a boolean field like `needsChecking` and [`$set`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set) this whenever the `modificationDate` is updated
- in your "check" procedure, find the documents that have this field set (should be fast due to the sparse index)

  > db.mycollection.find({'needsChecking':true});
- after you've done whatever check is needed, [`$unset`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24unset) the `needsChecking` field.

2) A new (and faster) feature in MongoDB 2.2 is the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/).

Here is an example of adding a "isUpdated" field based on the date comparison, and then filtering the matching documents:

```
    db.mycollection.aggregate(
            { $project: {
                    _id: 1,
                    name: 1,
                    type: 1,
                    modificationDate: 1,
                    lastCheckDate: 1,
                    isUpdated: { $gt:["$modificationDate","$lastCheckDate"] }
            }},
            { $match : {
                    isUpdated : true,
            }}
    )
```

Some current caveats of using the Aggregation Framework are:

- you have to specify fields to include aside from `_id`
- the result is limited to the current maximum BSON document size (16Mb in MongoDB 2.2)

Comment: the problem is this gives him new document with results - it doesn't persist the new computed field into the original document.

Comment: True, it depends if the computed field needs to be persisted or is just a transient value needed to find some records.  I did assume the latter.